Using NPM, Electron or a CLI program get information about the media that is currently playing on the computer
I am developing a application that will display the name and icon of the media that is currently playing on the PC. Something similar to the old windows banner when you changed your volume. I have not found a solution within Electron or a NPM library to be able to do this. I was wondering if anyone knew a way using Electron, A NPM library or a CLI tool to do this?
I have tried googling for something that would match this but I have no found anything.
I would like to be able to get the album/video artwork and the name of what is playing.
An example of the information I am trying to gather is here.
https://help.wallpaperengine.io/en/audio/mediaintegration.html

Being played by what?  I use Foobar2000 and Amazon Music, others use MediaMonkey, Sportify, Tidal, Qobuz, YouTube, Apple Music and more.  None of them ask the Windows OS to play songs, they just send raw audio data to the sound APIs.

@DaveS Yes but programs within windows can create a audio session. With that audio session small amounts of information about what is being played can be read. A good example is the old windows banner when you changed your volume or something like wallpaper engine which can show information about music that is currently playing.

Ah, so you want a way to read the "media overlay" / "media hotkey" data that apps might provide.  I'd do a search on what APIs are used to set the data, and see if there are matching APIs to get the data.

I ended up using the https://pypi.org/project/winrt/ python library and sending the information using a post request using express.
I tried using pipes with spawn but the information sent over the pipe was sent at inconsistent intervals and special characters like Japanese language characters would show incorrectly.
I also tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nodert-win11/windows.media.control but I could not get it working.
